# Is any chance to configure Asp.net with apache tomcat 7

Tags: asp.net, tomcat

I want my asp.net web application work under Apache tomcat server.  plz someone help me

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat is a a Java servlet container/application server. It has no idea about ASP.NET or .NET.

The correct approach would be using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) (the cross-platform, open-source .NET implementation), which [supports ASP.NET](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET).

Comment: and Apache web server, not Tomcat

Comment: Thanks man, But i must run my c# windows form client - server application using apache tomcat webserver . so only i trying asp.net web form is running on tomcat server.

Comment: @sounder: what? You must explain in **much** more detail what you want. A C# client doesn't imply an ASP.NET web form on the server, it should be able to communicate with any server (if it's written that way). And even if you **want** it to: Tomcat won't be able to execute your ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 0):

What environment are you using Windows/Linux? Try using [Grasshopper](http://dev.mainsoft.com/Default.aspx?tabid=51)

Comment: here . i'm using windows xp only, microsoft visual studio 2010. so plz help me for that